# Java TCP Socket - Human Readable Output

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi

I have a TCP socket that I am opening with Java on a Raspberry Pi and a remote piece of hardware is sending data to it. Unfortunately, the data being presented to the console is not readable to the sser.

[image: Data at the Console]

The Java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception       {
        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);
        while(true)          {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);

            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';

            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked with tcpdump and the hardware itself, the data is being sent and recieved by the Raspberry Pi. My hunch is the line:

```
clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
```

The end requirement is to take the data being sent and dump it into an SQL table, so I need to translate the TCP packet to a human readable string, hence my stumbling block here.

Comment: If your hardware sends a binary stream to the raspi, you should find out which protocol is used. If the device sends text to the raspi then you should find out what character encoding they use. (It is surely not ASCII) Perhaps UTF-16 or UTF-32. Write the input stream in file `file.txt` and enter `file <path to file>` in the shell. If Java knows the character set you can configure the input stream to translate into Java Strings.

Answer (score 0):

If your remote hardware is sending binary data, you should read it with a plain InputStream:

```
InputStream input=connectionSocket.getInputStream();
```

... and it won't be readable to a human user.

If, instead, you know certainly that it is text, you must know then in which charset it has been encoded, and set it to the InputStreamReader as a second parameter:

```
new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-16")
```

Possible encodings:

- ASCII
- UTF-8
- UTF-16
- ISO-8859-1
- ISO-8859-2
- BIG-5 (for Chinese)